# std::variant in a template input in c++ does not work?

Tags: c++

The following code gives me this error

```
main.cpp:22:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass’ to ‘const MyClass >&’
main.cpp:22:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr MyClass >::MyClass(MyClass >&&)’
main.cpp:22:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass’ to ‘MyClass >&&’"
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct InputClass1{
    static std::string MyName(){
        return "InputClass1";
    }
};

struct InputClass2{
    static std::string MyName(){
        return "InputClass2";
    }
};



template<class InputClass>
class MyClass{
    public:
     MyClass(){
         std::cout<<InputClass::MyName();
     }
};

class MyCreatorClass{
    using VariantType = std::variant<InputClass1, InputClass2>;

    public:
       static std::shared_ptr<MyClass<VariantType>> create(){
           return std::make_shared<MyClass<VariantType>>(MyClass<InputClass1>());
       } // Am I using the variant the right way here?
};



int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    MyCreatorClass::create();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what "does not work" means?

Comment: Why are you using a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @273K I get a `"main.cpp:22:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass’ to ‘const MyClass >&’
main.cpp:22:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr MyClass >::MyClass(MyClass >&&)’
main.cpp:22:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass’ to ‘MyClass >&&’"` error

Comment: isnt this the same question as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73626013/stdvariant-does-not-seem-to-work-with-shared-ptr-in-c ? (and again important information seems to be cut off from the error message)

Comment: why do you not apply what has been suggested in the answer on the other question? The one you accepted

Comment: `MyClass` expects `InputClass` to be one of your two classes, but gets `std::variant`.

Comment: You cannot construct `MyClass<Variant>` given an xvalue of type `MyClass<InputClass1>` as constructor parameter, therefore the syntax in the `create` function is incorrect. Furthermore you cannot specialize the default constructor of `MyClass` with `VariantType` as template parameter, since `std::variant` is lacking a member `MyName`, so you won't be able to construct any object of that type without UB...

Comment: You may be looking for something like this btw: `template<class ... InputClasses>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<class T>
    MyClass(T&&) requires (std::is_same_v<T, InputClasses> || ...)
    {
        std::cout << T::MyName() << '\n';
    }
}; ... return std::make_shared<MyClass<InputClass1, InputClass2>>(MyClass<InputClass1, InputClass2>(InputClass1{}));` or `template<class InputClass>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<class T> MyClass(T&&) { std::cout << T::MyName() << '\n'; } }; ... return std::make_shared<MyClass<VariantType>>(MyClass<VariantType>(InputClass1{}));`

Answer (score 0):

A `MyClass<std::variant<InputClass1, InputClass2>>` has no relation to a `MyClass<InputClass1>`.  Therefore the latter cannot be used to construct the former without a user-defined converting constructor.

You don't need to do that though.  You just need to fix the return type of `MyCreatorClass::create`:

```
class MyCreatorClass{
    using VariantType = std::variant<MyClass<InputClass1>, MyClass<InputClass2>>;

    public:
       static VariantType create() {
           return MyClass<InputClass1>();
       }
};
```